# Android ExpandableListAdapter View layout not displaying as desired :-(

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an XML layout for a view representing one item as displayed by a ExpandableListAdapter.  (The XML that is duplicated once for each list item, not the main activity layout).  I initially tried a LinearLayout but this hid the final of the three widgets (a image button).  I understand why that doesn't work but I then tried a RelativeLayout but the text view does not show.

I'll display the relative layout first along with a screenshot and also append my initial layout and screenshot at the bottom FWIW.  Thanks for any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkParent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:checked="false"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtParent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/chkParent"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/strItem"/>
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnExpand"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edtParent"
        android:src="@drawable/dark_expand"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hint="@string/strViewSubItems"
        android:contentDescription="@string/strViewSubItems"
        android:background="@null"/>  
 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screenshot for relative layout]

Original linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkParent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtParent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/strItem"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnExpand"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dark_expand"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hint="@string/strViewSubItems"
        android:contentDescription="@string/strViewSubItems"
        android:background="@null"/>  
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image: screenshot for linear layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your `toLeftOf` attributes should be `toRightOf` attributes. Give that a shot and see what happens.

Actually, your `EditText` should be set `toRightOf="@id/chkParent"` and `toLeftOf="@id/btnExpand`. Your `ImageButton` doesn't even need the `toRightOf` modifier, the `alignParentRight` attribute should cover it.

Comment: Doh...that was a brain fart on the toLeftOf, I was putting it back together again when I posted it...but yes, having the edit text with both left of and right of properties fixed it...that had me put the image button as the second element and the edit last, cause I guess the compiler only does one pass on XML apparently?

Comment: Ah, there's a way around that, just use `@+id/` instead of `@id/` when you're referencing one further down in the XML and you'll be able to keep it in order. Basically you just use the `+` the first time you reference an ID in the XML, whether you're setting an ID, or just referring to it.

Comment: Oh, nice!  Good to know.  Thanks for being so helpful as always brother! :-)